# Different reject_ifs based on the action in RAILS 3 (nested attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want different reject_ifs during creation and during the update action.

I have here nested attributes for **Attachment** model

```
has_many :attachments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['attachment_description'].blank? }
```

I want a specific `:reject_if` option for create action and another specific option for update action...

For example:

On Update...

Rejects if description is blank or nil:

```
:reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['attachment_description'].blank? }
```

On Create...
Rejects if file name is blank or nil:

```
:reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['attachment_file_name'].blank? }
```

I am not sure also how to implement `:on=> :update` and `:on=> :create` in `accepts_nested_attributes_for` block

Any workarounds will be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Tried to use it this way but no luck.

```
has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['attachment'].blank? }, on: :create
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :allow_destroy => true, on: :update
```

It says...

```
undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `attributes` hash is nil, so you can't access its `'attachment'` key.

You should ensure that the hash is never nil, and if you can't, change the proc to handle the nil case.